# How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests, pycurl, httplib, httplib2

I am making HTTP requests using the requests library in python, but I need the IP address from the server that responded to the HTTP request and I'm trying to avoid making two calls (and possibly having a different IP address from the one that responded to the request).

Is that possible? Does any python HTTP library allow me to do that?

PS: I also need to make HTTPS requests and use an authenticated proxy.

**Update 1:**

Example:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://user:password@10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://user:password@10.10.1.10:1080",
}

response = requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
response.ip # This doesn't exist, this is just an what I would like to do
```

Then, I would like to know to which IP address requests are connected from a method or property in the response. In other libraries, I was able to do that by finding the sock object and using the `getpeername()` function.

Comment: "The server that responded" is ambiguous, because there may be all sorts of proxies, load balancers etc between you and the machine that actually generates the response. And a given domain name may have multiple IP addresses in DNS.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It turns out that it's rather involved.

Here's a monkey-patch while using `requests` version 1.2.3:

Wrapping the `_make_request` method on `HTTPConnectionPool` to store the response from `socket.getpeername()` on the `HTTPResponse` instance.

For me on python 2.7.3, this instance was available on `response.raw._original_response`.

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool

def _make_request(self,conn,method,url,**kwargs):
    response = self._old_make_request(conn,method,url,**kwargs)
    sock = getattr(conn,'sock',False)
    if sock:
        setattr(response,'peer',sock.getpeername())
    else:
        setattr(response,'peer',None)
    return response

HTTPConnectionPool._old_make_request = HTTPConnectionPool._make_request
HTTPConnectionPool._make_request = _make_request

import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
print r.raw._original_response.peer
```

Yields:

```
('2a00:1450:4009:809::1017', 80, 0, 0)
```

---

Ah, if there's a proxy involved or the response is chunked, the `HTTPConnectionPool._make_request` isn't called.

So here's a new version patching `httplib.getresponse` instead:

```
import httplib

def getresponse(self,*args,**kwargs):
    response = self._old_getresponse(*args,**kwargs)
    if self.sock:
        response.peer = self.sock.getpeername()
    else:
        response.peer = None
    return response


httplib.HTTPConnection._old_getresponse = httplib.HTTPConnection.getresponse
httplib.HTTPConnection.getresponse = getresponse

import requests

def check_peer(resp):
    orig_resp = resp.raw._original_response
    if hasattr(orig_resp,'peer'):
        return getattr(orig_resp,'peer')
```

Running:

```
>>> r1 = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>> check_peer(r1)
('2a00:1450:4009:808::101f', 80, 0, 0)
>>> r2 = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
>>> check_peer(r2)
('2a00:1450:4009:808::101f', 443, 0, 0)
>>> r3 = requests.get('http://wheezyweb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#what-you-ll-build')
>>> check_peer(r3)
('162.209.99.68', 80)
```

Also checked running with proxies set; proxy address is returned.

---

**Update** 2016/01/19

[est](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41948/est) offers [an alternative that doesn't need the monkey-patch](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2158):

```
rsp = requests.get('http://google.com', stream=True)
# grab the IP while you can, before you consume the body!!!!!!!!
print rsp.raw._fp.fp._sock.getpeername()
# consume the body, which calls the read(), after that fileno is no longer available.
print rsp.content
```

---

**Update** 2016/05/19

From the comments, copying here for visibility, [Richard Kenneth Niescior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324832/richard-kenneth-niescior) offers the following that is confirmed working with requests 2.10.0 and Python 3.

```
rsp=requests.get(..., stream=True)
rsp.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()
```

---

**Update** 2019/02/22

Python3 with requests version 2.19.1.

```
resp=requests.get(..., stream=True)
resp.raw._connection.sock.socket.getsockname()
```

---

**Update** 2020/01/31

Python3.8 with requests 2.22.0

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.google.com', stream=True)
resp.raw._connection.sock.getsockname()
```

Comment: It's not pretty but it works. Thanks! That helped a lot!

Comment: There's a "fine" tradition of monkey patching... The requests library is a high level abstraction of HTTP, it doesn't consider the IP address that served a response to be needful at its abstraction level. The minimal monkey patch was an interesting challenge. If you want pretty you'd have to use a lower level HTTP library, but do more HTTP logic yourself.

Comment: I've just realized that it doesn't work in all cases. Is not working for http://wheezyweb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#what-you-ll-build. Can you tell a reason?

Comment: It didn't work for me. But I've managed to find the sock by changing your code to, response.fp._sock:
        response.peer = response.fp._sock.getpeername()

Comment: Perhaps a difference between versions.

Comment: Great solution: thanks. I had a problem with HTTPS connections: the "WrappedSocket" object didn't have the getpeername() method. I eventually found the method on self.sock.socket, so a two-step try/except for self.sock.getpeername() then self.sock.socket.getpeername() does the job for me: working on my web monitor service.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me show that inconsistent results from an API were not due to load balancing.

Comment: @MattH I found a new way  without the need to monkeymatch: `rsp=requests.get(..., stream=True);ip=rsp.raw._fp.fp._sock.getpeername();print rsp.content` see https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2158

Comment: @est Interesting! Added it into the body here. Don't know if it was possible back with 1.2.3, but certainly works with 2.5.1 that I have to hand.

Comment: I've just needed this and I have discovered that `rsp=requests.get(..., stream=True);rsp.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()` works. I have `requests 2.10.0` and am using Python 3

Comment: @RichardKennethNiescior - your solution works but when requesting via a proxy the IP address returned is the proxy's ip address but not the origin server IP address. Any idea how to get the origin server's ip address?

Comment: @SureshKumar: If you're using a HTTP proxy then your client never sees the IP address of the service beyond the proxy, your client asks the proxy by URL. If you're using an HTTPS proxy, then your client resolves the IP address and asks the proxy for a `CONNECT` to the resolved address and the HTTPS port. The proxy may add a header for an HTTP request, but may be a feature / setting.

Comment: It seems to be `resp.raw._connection.sock.socket.getsockname()` now with requests version '2.19.1'.
Note that in my case, `resp.raw._connection.sock` is of type `urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.WrappedSocket`.

Comment: How would I go about adding a proxy IP to the solution for Python 3?

Comment: on python 3.8 requests 2.22.0 call.raw._connection.sock does not have socket property even i'm using stream=True. for example 
getta = requests.get("https://www.google.it", stream=True) 
print(getta.raw._connection.sock.socket.getsockname())
returns
AttributeError: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'socket'
i'm not able to find where socket is.

Comment: @AndreaBisello Updated. `sock` was the socket.

Comment: @MattH `getsockname()` is the local name, `getpeername()` is the remote name, you're mixing both in your reply with your updates.

Comment: You are doing a great job keeping this answer updated!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://user:password@10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://user:password@10.10.1.10:1080",
}

response = requests.get('http://jsonip.com', proxies=proxies)
ip = response.json()['ip']
print('Your public IP is:', ip)
```

Comment: That's great and all, but how does this work when trying to obtain that local and/or remote ip when pulling a different url which 99.9% of people using requests will be doing? This works in a testing environment when you're testing basic code. But in production, you would never do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** 2023/08/08:

For Python 3.11.3 & requests 2.30.0, use the following monkey-patch:

```
def patch_http_and_https_connection():
    import http.client

    def getresponse(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = self._old_getresponse(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.sock:
            response._local = self.sock.getsockname()
            response._remote = self.sock.getpeername()
        else:
            response._local = None
            response._remote = None
        return response

    http.client.HTTPConnection._old_getresponse = http.client.HTTPConnection.getresponse
    http.client.HTTPConnection.getresponse = getresponse
```

Then for this example:

```
rsp = requests.get('https://www.google.com', stream=True)
```

Use the following:

```
Remote IP Address/Port = rsp.raw._original_response._remote
Local IP Address/Port = rsp.raw._original_response._local
```