# How to Get the IP address of the URL in requests module in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-requests

Python Version : 3.5.1

requests version: 2.9.1.

I am trying to get the IP address of url in python's request like below as explained here: [How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library/22513161#22513161)

```
import requests
rsp = requests.get('http://google.com', stream=True)
# grab the IP while you can, before you consume the body!!!!!!!!
print (rsp.raw._fp.fp._sock.getpeername())
# consume the body, which calls the read(), after that fileno is no longer available.
print (rsp.content)
```

Getting below error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute '_sock'
```

May be some version issues. Please help.

P.S. Unable to comment in original post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got to the [`BufferedReader` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader); it is a wrapper around the actual file object adding a buffer. The original file object is reachable via the [`raw` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.raw):

```
print(rsp.raw._fp.fp.raw._sock.getpeername())
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> rsp = requests.get('http://google.com', stream=True)
>>> print(rsp.raw._fp.fp.raw._sock.getpeername())
('2a00:1450:400b:c02::69', 80, 0, 0)
```

To make the code work on both Python 2 and 3, see if the `raw` attribute is there:

```
fp = rsp.raw._fp.fp
sock = fp.raw._sock if hasattr(fp, 'raw') else fp._sock
print(sock.getpeername())
```