# socket.gethostbyname not working for my ddns hostname

Tags: python, sockets, dns, ping

I have the following code to ping my ddns hostname and return if the host is up or down. I then tried adding the `socket.gethostbyname` which works for my normal hostname `www.iamsimonsmale.co.uk` but not `http://ssmale.ddns.net`.

I have tried to remove the `http://` from the start of the address and this fails too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This script checks to see if the server is up or down and prints the pinged IP

import requests
import socket
import time

while True:

    host = 'http://ssmale.ddns.net'

    ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

    print ip

    response = requests.get(host)
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print('Server Up')
    else:
        print('Server Down')
    time.sleep(10)
```

the error message for `http://ssmale.ddns.net` is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PingTestIP.py", line 12, in <module>
ip = socket.gethostbyname('http://ssmale.ddns.net')
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

and for `ssmale.ddns.net` is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PingTestIP.py", line 16, in <module>
response = requests.get(host)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 443, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 374, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 304, in prepare
self.prepare_url(url, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 358, in prepare_url
"Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'ssmale.ddns.net': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://ssmale.ddns.net?
```

and when done with `www.iamsimonsmale.co.uk it works and the print is

```
86.136.251.202
Server Up
```

I have also tried to use the code from [How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library) without success.

Using this tool (http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx#) i confirmed that there is an A record in the DNS for ssmale.ddns.net

What is causing the issue and how would i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query for the address without the `http://` part:

```
ip = socket.gethostbyname('ssmale.ddns.net')
```

And then use the full address in your requests query:

```
response = requests.get("http://ssmale.ddns.net")
```

Works on my machine:

```
>>> import socket

>>> socket.gethostbyname("ssmale.ddns.net")
'86.136.251.202'

>>> import requests

>>> requests.get("http://ssmale.ddns.net")
<Response [200]>
```

The error message you posted says it already: `No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://ssmale.ddns.net?`

Comment: Looking at it now its obvious. I didn't think about using both. Thank you for your help

Comment: @TheStudent It's always more obvious in hindsight. Glad I could help.