# How to get the ip address when to browse the domain name?

Tags: python, dns, ip, python-requests

```
dig www.sina.com.cn
jupiter.sina.com.cn.        30      IN      A       183.232.24.117
jupiter.sina.com.cn.        30      IN      A       183.232.24.115
jupiter.sina.com.cn.        30      IN      A       183.232.24.112
jupiter.sina.com.cn.        30      IN      A       183.232.24.114
jupiter.sina.com.cn.        30      IN      A       183.232.24.111
jupiter.sina.com.cn.        30      IN      A       183.232.24.113
jupiter.sina.com.cn.        30      IN      A       183.232.24.116
```

It means that the domain www.sina.com.cn can be parsed as one of seven ips as above.

I want to know which ip is exactly to be visited for the following codes.

```
import requests
source = 'http://www.sina.com.cn'
r = requests.get(source)
print(r.headers)
```

{'Server': 'nginx', 'Expires': 'Fri, 03 Feb 2017 06:41:23 GMT', 'Date': 'Fri, 03 Feb 2017 06:40:23 GMT', 'Age': '10', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Length': '133766', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'X-Cache': 'HIT from cmnet.xxg.18a4.34.spool.sina.com.cn', 'X-Powered-By': 'shci_v1.03', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=60', 'Last-Modified': 'Fri, 03 Feb 2017 06:40:00 GMT'}

There is no ip address info.

```
ping  cmnet.xxg.18a4.34.spool.sina.com.cn
ping: unknown host cmnet.xxg.18a4.34.spool.sina.com.cn
```

Which ip address is being visited when to send a request to domain name **www.sina.com.cn** with above python codes?
To open wireshark to monitor the process.

[image]

At this time www.sina.com.cn is parsed into 183.232.24.111,maybe next time it may be parsed into 183.232.24.117,no matter which one,i want it to be displayed by my python codes.

[image]

The ip will be changed from one into other in the range     (183.232.24.111-183.232.24.117).

Comment: You see a round robin DNS setup that *intentionally* returns one IP address out of a pool. This is used mainly for load balancing and fail over. Also there is a reverse proxy involved for the same reasons. All of that does not really matter to the user and most likely also not to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.sina.com.cn', stream=True)
>>> r.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()
('151.249.91.56', 80)
```

[Body Content Workflow](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow)

[more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library)