# Catch the IP and Port from a Head request

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
try:
    r = requests.head(url='http://'+finalURL, headers=headers, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=True)

    try:
        print('Status', r.status_code)
        print('Headers', r.headers)
        print('Elapsed Total', r.elapsed.total_seconds())

    except NameError as e:
        print("Undefined variable", e)
```

I have tried this: `print(r.raw._original_response.peer)` as I saw on another answer on here, but it doesn't work.

Another option is `stream=True` but in this case `Timeout` won't work, thats what I read somewhere.

How can I catch the IP and Port?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Its not a duplicate `r.raw._original_response.peer` doesn't work. This is a `head` not a `get` request!

Comment: I don' think it is supported. https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2158

Answer (score 1):

If `stream=True` is acceptable:

```
response=requests.head('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149424/catch-the-ip-and-port-from-a-head-request',stream=True)
print response.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()
('151.101.129.69', 443)
```

Comment: Timeout won't work with `stream=True` enabled. It's what I read somewhere. Otherwise it works perfectly.