# How can I see in debug logs which IP address is used for connection by Python's request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, python-requests, python-logging

Let us say I am sending a GET request to an URL which's DNS record contains multiple IP addresses (DNS Round-Robin). For example, to the `https://www.twitter.com`. If we do `dig` of it, we see:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
twitter.com.        60  IN  A   104.244.42.193
twitter.com.        60  IN  A   104.244.42.129
```

I have tried to use DEBUG logging as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630836/1479414
however it does not show which IP address it uses.

Furthermore, I looked also at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22513161/1479414 about how to see the destination IP address, but it is not what I actually want to see -- this one shows me the finally used IP address.

I want rather to see which IP addresses are tried during all attempts, while the library performs DNS failover. Something like:

`Trying to connect to 104.244.42.193... failed, trying to connect using another IP address`

Is it possible to see somehow?

Comment: [This is the line that resolves name to IP address](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/11d68efa7c150823472f0e5309c3a08a1a10c2f2/src/urllib3/util/connection.py#L61). [`socket.getaddrinfo()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) produces a list of tuples to try.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay, so do you mean that's not possible to log somehow?

Comment: There is zero logging there, so you'd have to patch that area.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, it sounds like a definite answer which I would accept for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `urllib3` library is responsible for this, in the [`urllib3.util.connection.create_connection()` function](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/11d68efa7c150823472f0e5309c3a08a1a10c2f2/src/urllib3/util/connection.py#L29-L86). There's a loop there that checks each result from [`socket.getaddrinfo()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo):

```py
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    #  ....
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        # ...
        sock.connect(sa)
        return sock

    except socket.error as e:
        # ...
```

Unfortunately, there is no logging used in this section. If you must have logging, you'd have to copy the function source, add in the logging you need, then monkeypatch the `urllib3` code to use your version instead.

The only location that uses that function uses it [as an attribute on the imported module](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/063d888bc247eb6bd7aedcd32412bbb53c3c6ffb/src/urllib3/connection.py#L156-L158), so at least monkeypatching is as simple as assigning it back to original function location:

```
import urllib3.util.connection

def create_connection_with_logging(
    address,
    timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
    source_address=None,
    socket_options=None,
):
    # ....

urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = create_connection_with_logging
```

Comment: What do you think, would it be valuable to propose such a PR for the library?

Comment: @Andremoniy: perhaps, you could file a FR issue first and propose you create a PR for this. The maintainers can then give you feedback on this.