# how to get REMOTE ADDRESS using requests - python

Tags: python, python-requests, ip-address

I'm making a tool where it logs `URLs` to `IP Addresses`, I've done one other project with **requests** but I don't know how to get the `Remote Address` value under `General` in my **browser networking tab** in the dev tools.

Here is a Screenshot of what I'm wanting to get:
[image: networking tab for XHR requests]

It's not listed as a header or something I can request with a `param=` flag. I don't know how to automate getting that information, can you please tell me if it's possible with **requests** or any other module in python.

Comment: This probably answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library

Comment: @michalwa thanks that works, I even looked at that question **facepalm**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library)

Comment: You don't need requests for this... You just need to resolve DNS, so no HTTP required. I.e. you can use `ping`, or `dig` or `nslookup`