# I wanna get my current proxy ip in requests python

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

my code :

```
proxies = {
  "http": "http://user:password@10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://user:password@10.10.1.10:1080",
}
response = requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
print(response.ip) # This doesn't exist, this is just an what I would like to do
```

the result must be : 10.10.1.10 (**the proxy that i used in my code**)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library)