# get server ip from response of httpx get

Tags: python, httpx

As the title says, if I do `resp=httpx.get(url)` how do I get the IP from which the `url` was resolved?

There's [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library) question about how to do it with `requests` but the same methods don't appear to exist in the `httpx` objects.

Comment: Do you really need to do this via httpx, or would just `socket.gethostbyname(...)` do?

Comment: @AKX The site I'm downloading from has a load balancer so the server, and by extension IP, requests are served by isn't always the same.  Can we know for certain that, in serial calls to `socket.gethostbyname` and then `httpx.get`, they'll be the same server or is there a chance they'd be different?

Comment: We can't know for sure, and proxies etc. will muddle the waters further. See my answer for an ugly incantation though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empirically, you can do it with an exquisitely ugly incantation like as follows.

Do note that this involves digging into no less than 6 underscore-private attribute of the response stream, so it could stop working at any time when you upgrade `httpx`. (This worked for me with httpx 0.23.0.)

```
import httpx

with httpx.Client() as hc:
    r = hc.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
    peername = r.stream._stream._httpcore_stream._stream._connection._network_stream._sock.getpeername()
    print(r.json())
    print(peername)
```

This prints out

```
{'args': {}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-httpx/0.23.0', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=...'}, 'origin': '....', 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/get'}
('44.207.168.240', 443)
```

Comment: How did you come up with that so fast?  Are you a contributor to httpx and knew where to look right away?

Comment: No - I just used a debugger to dig into the responses object since I knew it would have to contain a reference to the socket, or the data wouldn't be readable via it :)

Comment: Here's an easier way (which also works when using Trio and will likely not "break" as easily): 

response.extensions['network_stream'].get_extra_info('server_addr') 
response.extensions['network_stream'].get_extra_info('client_addr')

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to solve the same problem.  I was concerned about forward the compatibility of the "exquisitely ugly incantation" provided in the answer here.  I'm using httpx with Trio, and realized I can use the Trio socket implementation to use an async version of sockets to answer this question.
see: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-io.html#trio.socket.getaddrinfo

I posted this question to the httpx Q&A and got this answer: https://github.com/encode/httpx/discussions/2633#discussioncomment-5439764
In short, access to this information is provided through httpcore.  There is an open issue to update the documentation.

```py
import httpx

with httpx.Client() as client:
    with client.stream("GET", "https://httpbin.org/get") as response:
        network_stream = response.extensions["network_stream"]
        server_addr = network_stream.get_extra_info("server_addr")
        print(response.json())
        print(server_addr)
```

read: https://www.encode.io/httpcore/extensions/#extra-network-information