# Python Requests lib - How to get IP address of connected host after getting the response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to understand how I could access information about host that the request connected to. I have situation when behind a hostname, there is a multiple IP addresses that you can connect to, so for example `x.com` can route me to `1.2.3.4` or `2.3.4.5`. I need that information after receiving response from requests. I'm using python 3.10 if that matters.

My code is as follows:

```
retry_strategy = Retry(total=1,
backoff_factor=0.5,
status_forcelist=[400, 408, 429, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504],
raise_on_status=False)
        
self.adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)

# other, not important code

s = Session()
s.mount('https://', self.adapter)
response = s.get(url, headers=self.headers, stream=True, timeout=60)
```

Where (if anywhere?) should I look for that kind of information? I found something about `response.raw` but the connection there is declared as None.

Comment: What is the specific back-end mechanism that allows connecting to different IP addresses?  Is `x.com` a load balancer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the IP address from a http request using the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library)